# Processor Audio JavaScript HTML5

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, audio

There is a js-script:

```
<script>
function start1() {
var audio = new Audio();
audio.src = URL.createObjectURL(document.getElementById('f1').files[0]);
audio.autoplay = true;
}
function start2() {
var audio = new Audio();
audio.src = URL.createObjectURL(document.getElementById('f2').files[0]);
audio.autoplay = true;
}
...
function stop() {
var audio = new Audio();
audio.stop();
}
</script>
```

and html code:

```
<body>
<input type="file" id="f1"></input>
<input type="file" id="f2"></input>
...
<button onmousedown="start1()" onmouseup="stop()">1</button>
<button onmousedown="start2()" onmouseup="stop()">2</button>
...
```

As can be understood through the script, he plays a sound file that loads by using the form files.

But there are two problems:
1) requires that sound is played only during events pressing (onmousedown) and stops when the mouse button is released (onmouseup).
Now the sound is played to the end it does not matter whether you clicked the mouse button and let go of it (because there is no test for this condition).
2) also need to create a simplified version of the script, as the functions for processing should be 16 pieces, but not manually register the same each function. You must create a generated script that will process the N-number of id (start1, start2, etc., f1, f2, etc).

Help to modify the code, you can also fully code jquery. It is not critical.
Thank you.

Comment: Your problem happens because you only create local vars inside the function, so they can't be accessed from another function. Also you use always the same var names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use local variables, you just need an identifier to find the audio element later. You also need to append the audio element to the DOM.

Also, you have to use pause() not stop().

```
        <script>
        function start(id, source) {
                var aud = document.getElementById(id);

                if (aud) {
                    aud.parentNode.removeChild(aud);
                }

                var audio = new Audio();
                audio.setAttribute("id", id);
                audio.src = URL.createObjectURL(document.getElementById(source).files[0]);
                document.body.appendChild(audio);
                audio.autoplay = true;
            }

            function stop(id) {
                var aud = document.getElementById(id);
                aud.pause();
            }
    </script>

    <input type="file" id="f1"></input>
    <input type="file" id="f2"></input>
    <button onmousedown="start('1', 'f1')" onmouseup="stop('1')">1</button>
    <button onmousedown="start('2', 'f2')" onmouseup="stop('2')">2</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work (Untested):

`<script>
    var a1 = new Audio();
    var a2 = new Audio();
    function start1() {
        a1.src = URL.createObjectURL(document.getElementById('f1').files[0]);
        a1.autoplay = true;
    }
    function start2() {
        a2.src = URL.createObjectURL(document.getElementById('f2').files[0]);
        a2.autoplay = true;
    }
    function stop() {
        a1.stop();
        a2.stop();
    }
    </script>`

Comment: This example is not working. all the same as I had. You just asked VAR and carried them for function.