# Processing keydown and keyup [jquery]

Tags: jquery, audio, keydown, keyup

there is such a handler:

```
<script>
function start() {
    var audio = new Audio('URL');
    audio.play();
}

function stop() {
    var aud = document.getElementById(id);
    aud.pause();
    aud.currentTime = 0;
}

$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 81) {
        return start();
    }
});
$(document).keyup(function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 81) {
        return stop();
    }
});
</script>
```

The script works, but somehow wrong.
That is, it works one second, but then begins to re-run the recursion function start() which is why sound gets imposes on each other.

I also need to make the script work (reproduced sound) only during pressing and stop when you release it (the principle of a typical synthesizer).

Please help me with handlers keydown and keyup.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to set new variable. Something like `soundIsPlaying = false` and set it to true at the beginning of `start()` method and back go `false` at the end of the `stop` method. You only want to start playing sound if sound isn't turned on already.

The reason for that is user potentially can press Start button much faster then it takes for sound to complete and you have to check somehow if you have to enable music now or not.

P.S. Be sure to set this variable somewhere in the upper scope of your program, so it will keep it's state between start/stop method calls.

Comment: I do not know how it will help, but here is my complete script [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30356782/processor-audio-javascript-html5/30357884#30357884). With the mouse works just fine, but the keyboard harder.
I can not catch the event keypress, the event keyup.